Trouble with writing to csv file in C# WPF application
I need to log the current date and time, along with the current counter value of my program into a csv file. Its started with a button that starts a counter, which runs a method that does the logging. My problem is just the correct way to build the bethod, which I cannot figure out.
The timer and header bool are determined under Mainwindow : Window
private DispatcherTimer autoLogTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
private bool headersWritten = false;

And the timer and the filepath are determined under InitializeComponent();
autoLogTimer.Tick += LogIntoFile;
autoLogTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
txtLogPath.Text = "D:\\Programming\\Robot\\log file.csv";

The logging starts with the button press, and stops with another button.
private void btnStartLog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    headersWritten = false; // This resets the bool when starting a new log
    autoLogTimer.Start();
}

private void btnStopLog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    autoLogTimer.Stop();
}

And finally, the logging is done via LogIntoFile method. This method is run with the autoLogTimer and should log everything every 3 seconds. The headers should be above the text, and the text should be logged under the headers each 3 seconds. The headers should appear only once per button press, and appear on every button press, so you can see how many times the logging has been started from the file.
private void LogIntoFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string logLine = $"{DateTime.Now},{txtCounter.Text}{Environment.NewLine}";

        if (!headersWritten)
        {
            // Write headers if they haven't been written yet
            File.WriteAllText(txtLogPath.Text, "Date    Quantity" + Environment.NewLine);
            headersWritten = true;
        }

        File.AppendAllText(txtLogPath.Text, logLine);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}. Check the file path.");
        autoLogTimer.Stop();
    }
}

Currently the File.WriteAllText shows red, with the error code "CS0103", "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context'. I've tried to build the method with different CsvHelper functions but could not get it to work the way I wanted. The final file should look like something similar to this:
Date:               Quantity:
1.1.2024          31
1.1.2024          32

The ways I've found on this site have not worked in my case, and anything proposed by ChatGPT has not worked either. The current version is my own making, not something made up by ChatGPT or found on this site.

File is a class in the  System.IO Library.  Do you have at top of module "using System.IO"

I see I didn't, now the logging works thank you! But do you happen to know how I can include the logging to different cells onto the logging "message". Now everything is logged into the first row on a excel file.

Use AppendAllText : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-8.0

@UunoPurhaturo - You may be missing a comma between your Date and Quantity column headers.  Try File.WriteAllText(txtLogPath.Text,  $"Date,Quantity{Environment.NewLine}");

By the way, your "final file" CSV text isn't actually comma separated.  Do you want a CSV file or a text file with fixed width fields?  You wrote, The final file should look like something similar to this: -- might you please [edit] your question to show exactly how the final file should look, rather than approximately how it should look?  The more details you share with us, the more likely we can help.  Thanks!

I strongly suggest replacing File IO with StreamWriter. You code should look something along those lines :
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     private DispatcherTimer autoLogTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     private bool headersWritten = false;
     private StreamWriter fileStream;
     private int txtCounter = 0;
     public MainWindow()
     {
         autoLogTimer.Tick += LogIntoFile;
         autoLogTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);

         string file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
         file = Path.Combine(file, "log.csv");
         fileStream = new StreamWriter(file,true);
         fileStream.AutoFlush = true;
         DataContext = this;
         InitializeComponent();
         autoLogTimer.Start();
     }

     private void LogIntoFile(object? sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
             string logLine = $"{DateTime.Now},{++txtCounter}{Environment.NewLine}";

             if (!headersWritten)
             {
                 fileStream.WriteLine("Date,Quantity");
                 headersWritten = true;
             }
             fileStream.WriteLine(logLine);

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}. Check the file path.");
             autoLogTimer.Stop();
         }
     }

     protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
     {
         fileStream.Close();
         fileStream.Dispose();
         base.OnClosed(e);
     }
 }

Note I have changed the path, so you would need to adjust it to your needs and make sure you have permission to manipulate it.
